# Why wouldn't Aang cut off Ozai's hands in S3 like what the Earthbenders were about to do to Iroh in S1?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

There's a whole issue towards the end of ATLA s3 of how Aang wants to defeat Ozai without killing Ozai.

In the entire history of their universe surely all 4 kinds of benders in some war must have been taken as POWs and so should know how to deal with this kinds of issues. Zuko offered to be a POW in s3. [Yon Rha for some reason wasn't.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/286417/why-wasnt-yon-rha-arrested-as-a-pow) In particular, [Iroh actually was](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267014/what-are-likely-to-not-be-considered-war-crimes-in-atla-tlok). They were about to cut off Iroh's hands.

So why wouldn't Aang do this? Like was it ever discussed as a possibility - maybe in the comics or something?

Comment: Aang seems more of the "*talk things out peacefully and only use violence as a last resort*" kinda guy, not the "*maim my enemies so they can't rise against me in the future*" sort.

Comment: @Valorum Lol this is the whole point. Maim instead of kill.

Comment: I wouldn't be too sure cutting off his hands would stop Ozai from being able to bend. There's all kinds of fiery kicks and firebreathing ("Dragon of the West") going on in the show. The waterbender with no arms in Korra too.

Comment: @Nolimon ok legs too.

Comment: Cutting off people's hands is not compassionate.