# Is Iroh complicit in any fire nation war crimes?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra, politics, crime

Considering Iroh was against Zhao's killing of the moon, a [weather modification war crime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_modification) and possibly even something ATLA-specific like a 'spiritual war crime' (maybe not so specific. could be like in our world 'don't attack churches or hospitals.' So here, 'don't attack a spirit oasis.'), Iroh presumably wouldn't stand for any fire nation war crimes. But who knows? Maybe Iroh turned a blind eye to them.

The main war crime I have in mind is when the fire nation [arrests/imprisons (or does even worse to) civilians who are earthbenders or waterbenders](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/286417/why-wasnt-yon-rha-arrested-as-a-pow), whether (falsely) as prisoners-of-war or (falsely) as actual prisoners. This is clearly a [war crime](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267014/what-are-likely-to-not-be-considered-war-crimes-in-atla-tlok) similar to in our world, idk, arresting any adult male between 18 & 35.

But maybe there's some propaganda [justification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266389/howd-the-fire-nation-justify-its-war-was-there-some-kind-of-propaganda-that-th) for this eg the fire nation tells its citizens and maybe even its officers 'Everyone we arrest necessarily did do some rebellion or something.'

**My question**: Is Iroh complicit in any war crimes such as the above? And specify degree of complicity: Did Iroh actually agree with or even oversee them? Or just merely turn a blind eye? Or even less: was a victim of propaganda?

- **Version: You can do any: netflix, m night shyamalan, original series or comics.**

Comment: I only watched the live-action series, but if it's similar enough to the cartoon, I think Iroh would be the first to admit that he was responsible for various atrocities. An Omashu soldier confronts him about it when he was captive, I think. Though, as I mentioned, the legal notion of war crimes just does not seem to exist at that point in the *Avatar* universe, due to the small number of relevant polities and the fact that the most industrially advanced nation is the one committing most of them.

Comment: @Adamant i remember that scene. did the soldier say iroh did anything that was a war crime? i thought the atrocity was simply the siege (an act of war but not a war crime). i watched the [netflix version very](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266389/howd-the-fire-nation-justify-its-war-was-there-some-kind-of-propaganda-that-th/286420#286420) carefully because it's part of [my own propaganda to say that in netflix the fire nation is the good guy.](https://qr.ae/psGT3h) Mwahahahaha.

Comment: The Fire Nation isn't "the good guy," in either the live-action or the cartoon versions. It's an expansionist empire run by a maniac with delusions of godhood who wants to rule the entire world and physically abuses his children, and by your own admission, regularly engages in war crimes, including the genocide of the Air Nomads and Zhao's attempted genocide of all waterbenders. Iroh is one of the people in the Fire Nation who has begun to see it (and his past actions) for what they are, which is what makes him more sympathetic than most of the Fire Nation characters we see.

Comment: As for the attempt in what I suppose you are saying is your post on Quora to tie this to ongoing real-world conflicts by equating the Fire Nation with Israel and the rest of the *Avatar* world with Hamas, it is, at minimum, not a good analogy at all and in somewhat bad taste.

Comment: You have at least a half-dozen posts about war crimes in *Avatar* in some fashion or another (some have been deleted), not to mention one of them is a question that you self-answered about *four* times, not to mention that, to judge from what you seem to be claiming is your post on Quora, you may be trying to use these questions to "prove" something about real-world conflicts or vice versa. And the name on the Quora post matches a user known for spamming chess conspiracy theories on other sites. This feels close to spamming to me.