# Why do Zuko & Iroh hide being fire benders / fire nation citizens?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender

Why in Ba Sing Se do Iroh & Zuko hide being a fire bender or fire nation citizen? Not all Russians support Putin. Or well maybe there so much [propaganda that most citizens actually do support the war](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266389/howd-the-fire-nation-justify-its-war-was-there-some-kind-of-propaganda-that-th/286420#286420). Idk.

Of course out-of-universe explanation is that it works great because of Jin & Jet, but well...

Answer (score 5):

The Earth Kingdom sees every firebender as an enemy because, in their perspective, all firebenders are soldiers. In the series, there is only one firebender who actually deserts the Fire Nation military.

Also, Zuko and Iroh are not normal firebenders, but the son and brother of the Fire Lord, respectively. It is more risky for them to be discovered than a normal firebender.