# Ethnicity in ATLA / TLOK

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

**Is there any such concept of ethnicity, race or something in ATLA/TLOK given everyone seemingly looks like everyone else?**

The average French cannot go to Japan and fool everyone 'I'm Japanese.' Lol. (But maybe it works for China & Japan. Not according to [Family Guy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTjFbKJYkkw) though.)

Here are some examples

1

Previously, I asked why: [Why do Zuko & Iroh hide being fire benders / fire nation citizens?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/286688/why-do-zuko-iroh-hide-being-fire-benders-fire-nation-citizens)

Now I'm wondering how Zuko & Iroh can hide being fire benders / fire nation citizens. The average French cannot go to Japan and say 'I'm Japanese'. Lol.

I mean I guess most fire nation citizens are so ethnically similar to most earth kingdom citizens that you couldn't tell them apart.

2. Aang somehow pretended to be an Earth Kingdom (or Water Tribe?) citizen in Omashu in s1.
3. Aang, Katara, Sokka somehow pretended to be Fire Nation citizens in s3 eg when Sokka & Katara pretended to be Wang & Sapphire Fire.
4. Probably there are some TLOK examples (before of course there were all those new airbenders), but none immediately come to mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this question derives from a mistaken premise, possibly exacerbated by the animation style, but quite clearly wrong if one considers the live-action series.

It is not the case that "everyone seemingly looks like everyone else."
Most of the Fire Nation looks more Han Chinese, while much of the Water Tribe looks Inuit (or more generally Indigenous North American) and so forth. The Air Nomads mainly look Tibetan. The Earth Kingdom is diverse, but a lot of people in Omashu in particular look Indian. People on Kyoshi Island look more Japanese.

None of the nations is homogeneous in appearance, but they do have appearances that are more typical, just like in real life. But there is variation within countries. There are people in China who are not Han Chinese, but rather of more Central Asian descent, and they will look closer to people from Tibet. The line between the appearances of people on the Indian side and the Chinese side of the India-China border is blurry, and there are people in China who would look more Indian and people in India who would look more Chinese.

The same thing applies to the world of *Avatar*. The average person in the Earth Kingdom is distinguishable from the average person in the Fire Nation, but there is a lot of variation in appearances nonetheless. If someone in Omashu sees Zuko, they are more likely to think "Oh, he must be from near Kyoshi Island" than "Oh, he must be from the Fire Nation."