# Was Kuvira charged for war crimes specifically and not for crime of aggression?

Tags: avatar-the-last-airbender, the-legend-of-korra

From [here](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72613/why-isnt-any-unprovoked-act-of-aggression-considered-a-war-crime/72619#72619), The Rome Statute of the International Criminal Courtdistinguishes 4 crimes:

- The crime of genocide;
- Crimes against humanity;
- War crimes;
- The crime of aggression.

Kuvira may have been charged with aggression or crimes against humanity, but was Kuvira charged with war crimes?

I checked [fandom](https://avatar.fandom.com/wiki/Kuvira) it seems just crimes of waging wars ([which I think is kinda weird](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/72613/why-isnt-any-unprovoked-act-of-aggression-considered-a-war-crime/86611#86611) because which [war isn't just](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/266389/howd-the-fire-nation-justify-its-war-was-there-some-kind-of-propaganda-that-th/286420#286420) from the perspective of its wager/aggressor? but ok) **but not necessarily [war crimes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267014/what-are-likely-to-not-be-considered-war-crimes-in-atla-tlok)**. Just double checking.

Comment: Could you flesh out the body of your question to make it a bit clearer and more self-contained? The title question seems clear, but then the post body reads like a stream of consciousness without actually containing the question itself.

Comment: @Randal'Thor thanks. edited.